# Self-Study: Uncountably discontinouities in CDF despite $\mathbb{P}(X = x) = 0$

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

Let $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ be a random variable and let $F_X(x)$ be it's cumulative distribution function. In $\mathbb{R}^1$, $\mathbb{P}(X = x) = 0$ implies that $F_X(x)$ is continuous. Show that for $k > 1$, $F_X$ can have a discontinuity despite $\mathbb{P}(X=x) = 0$.

Here is my approach:

if we take $k = 2$ and let $X = (X_1, 0)$ where $X_1$ is a RV with CDF $F_{X_1}$ which is continous everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $X \in \mathbb{R} \times {0} = \{ x=(x_1, 0): x_1 \in \mathbb{R} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

From here on, what is left is to show that $F_X$ has uncountably many discontinouity pts while $\mathbb{P}(X = x) = 0$. However I am stuck here.

Comment: Hint : $F_X(x_1,x_2)=\mathbb P\{X_1\le x_1,X_2\le x_2\}.$ Now use $X=(X_1,0)\,.$ What do you get?

Comment: Not quite. So this results in $\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leq x_1, 0 \leq x_2)$ with $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = x_1, 0 = x_2) \forall x_2 \neq 0$ thus $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \mathbb{P}(X = x + h) = 0$. The problem remains why there is an uncountable amount of discontinouities. Am i going in the right direction?

Comment: Because $X_2\equiv 0,$
$$
F_X(x_1,x_2)=\left\{\begin{array}\ \mathbb P\{X_1\le x_1\}&\text{ if }x_2\ge 0\,,\\0&\text{ else. }\end{array}\right.
$$
This function is discontinuous at $x_2=0$ whenever $\mathbb P\{X_1\le x_1\}>0.$